# Stop RTC baseline from being delivered

Tags: rtc, baseline, rational-team-concert

I created a baseline in my workspace and forgot I had some undelivered changes. These changes are not supposed to be part of the baseline.

The changes and baseline have not been delivered to the stream, is there anyway to get rid of this undelivered baseline and undelivered changes?

Would deleting the workspace and creating a new one work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/45624/deletingremoving-baselines?redirect=%2Fforum%2Fquestions%2F45624%2Fdeletingremoving-baselines) is clear:

> Both the internals and the users of RTC SCM system depend on the fact that a baseline is immutable.
>   A baseline is visible (via various search menus) as soon as it is created, **so it would not be safe to change the content of a baseline, even if you haven't yet delivered it**.
>   That is why RTC makes it very fast and cheap to create a new baseline whenever you need one.
>
> BUT I agree that you should be able to:

- drop a baseline from your outgoing changes list in the Pending Changes view ([Story 18512: Discard a baseline](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=18512): nothing done yet 8 years later) and:
- hide/archive a baseline:

  - [Enhancement 170855: Provide the ability to hide (archive) baselines that are no longer needed](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=170855), 2011, reformulated in
  - [Enhancement 169438: Need true database archive and restore capability for work items and SCM objects](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Jazz%20Collaborative%20ALM#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=169438): 2011, itself encompassed in
  - [Enhancement 294112: Archival techniques and tools](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Jazz%20Collaborative%20ALM#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=294112): 2013.
    Nothing is done yet.

---

So try simply to:

- rename your current baseline with a name which makes it clear it is not meant to be used,
- create a new baseline including only the change sets you want
- deliver both baselines